# vue.js: How to reuse a template in a component without exporting it as a new component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

There are times when you have to reuse a template inside a component. You cannot iterate them because they are not rendered sequentially. Consider the following example:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <template>
          <span>{{yearly.text}}</span>
          <span :class="spanClassName(yearly.increase)"><i :class="iconClassName"></i>{{yearly.increase}}%</span>
        </template>
        <YearlyChart/>
        <template>
          <span>{{monthly.text}}</span>
          <span :class="spanClassName(monthly.increase)"><i :class="iconClassName"></i>{{monthly.increase}}%</span>
        </template>
        <MonthlyTable/>
        <template>
          <span>{{weekly.text}}</span>
          <span :class="spanClassName(weekly.increase)"><i :class="iconClassName"></i>{{weekly.increase}}%</span>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    data() {
        return {
            yearly: {
                text: "Yearly Sales",
                increase: 5
            },
            monthly: {
                text: "Monthly Sales Dropping",
                increase: -7.2
            },
            weekly: {
                text: "Awesome Weekly Sales!",
                increase: 0.2
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        spanClassName: function(increase) {
            increase >= 0 ? 'text-success' : 'text-danger'
        },
        iconClassName: function(increase) {
            increase >= 0 ? 'fa fa-arrow-up' : 'fa fa-arrow-down'
        }
    }
</script>
```

I don't want to export this tiny template (composed of two `span` tags) as another component because I believe it's not very efficient.
In React, this can be done very simply:

```
const renderIncrease = (stat) => (
    <span>{stat.text}</span>
    <span className={this.spanClassName(stat)}><i className={this.iconClassName(stat)}>{stat.increase}</i></span>
)

render() {
    return (
        <>
            {renderIncrease(this.state.yearly)}
            // .. some other elements
            {renderIncrease(this.state.monthly)}
        </>
    )
}
```

Angular can do this too because it has template reference variable(#).

Does Vue.js has a similar feature like this?

Comment: Honestly i would extract that into a dedicated component. Yeah, the template will only have two lines of code, but that is no reason for me to not extract it. You end up with a very simple and reusable component - that is something good - in my opinion :)

Comment: What if that's only used in this component? Isn't it some kind of waste? Export it to a external file... does it affect to performace?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Comment: you can also use render function - and do kinda the same - but creating this renderIncrease function kinda equals creating a template equals crating a component - e.g. usage in a framework: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/b688a17a4b48cd70f689fb9e325a3978fc6779f9/packages/vuetify/src/components/VCheckbox/VSimpleCheckbox.ts#L45

Comment: I highly recommend checking out this article that shows all the different ways to make templates in [Vue](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/03/24/vue-js-component-templates/). You could probably make use of something like an X-Template or something.

Comment: But can you guys provide a working code as an example? Nothing helps more than code :)

Answer (score 2):

A workaround I have used which is ugly but works for your specific example is to use v-for, then only output the intermediate html based on v-for counter (or equality, "item == yearly" etc), eg:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <template v-for="item, idx in [yearly, monthly, weekly]">
          <span>{{item.text}}</span>
          <span :class="spanClassName(item.increase)"><i :class="iconClassName"></i>{{item.increase}}%</span>
          <YearlyChart v-if="idx == 0"/>
          <MonthlyTable v-if="idx == 1"/>
        </template>                       
    </div>
</template>
```

Untested, but you get the idea :)

I think this is a flaw in Vue, not being able to define a "local" template, as I often want to duplicate a button (e.g. Save) at the top and bottom of my page. I am totally against the idea suggested in the comments of creating a separate component as I hate having my project polluted with files that are only relevant to another single component.

Answer (score -6):

Try this

```
<ng-template #nameRef >
        {{ theContent}}
</ng-template>
```

and then

```
ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="nameRef"></ng-template>
```

Comment: This is angular, the question is about vue.js.